# Add column based on two existing column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use pandas to look at two existing columns in a tsv file and add a new column where `df['padj'] < 0.01` and `df['log2FoldChange'] > 0.1`. I would like the new column to contain the string `Up-Regulated` where this condition is met.

This is the code I've come up with so far:

```
if df[(df['padj'] < 0.01) & (df['log2FoldChange'] > 0.1)]:
    df["Up/Down-Regulated"] = "Up-Regulated"
```

However, I'm running into this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: your if-statement won't be `True` or `False`, because it will result in a `df` which is filtered to where the 2 conditions are met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`pandas.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

```
df.loc[(df['padj'] < 0.01) & (df['log2FoldChange'] > 0.1), ["Up/Down-Regulated"]] = "Up-Regulated"
```